# insert data from another table where ids match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert some data from one table into another.

For example, I have a table `a.user` and `b.user` (2 tables in different schemas)

Both tables have columns `id` where some of the ids match. For the matching ids, I want to insert some data from `a.user.userSettings` into `b.user.userSettings`.

I am able to do a simple select + inner join to get the `userSettings` where ids from both tables match.

Now,I tried inserting this into `b.users`, and it is not working.

Here is my query:

```
insert into b.user ("userSettings") select "userSettings" from a.user
inner join b.user
on a.user.id = b.users.id
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SQL Error [23502]: ERROR: null value in column "username" violates not-null constraint
```

I don't understand the error, and why it is complaining about the column `username` when I am not trying to insert anything into that column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to *update* rows in `b`, not insert them:

```
update b.user b
    set userSettings = a.userSettings
    from a.user a
    where a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: ah, i thought insert would simply copy the rows. Update works just perfect, thanks!